About Hall subgroups. Given $\pi$, with at least 2 prime numbers, prove that there exists a finite group G such that G has not a Hall $\pi$-subgroup
Given $\pi$, a set of prime numbers with at least 2 prime numbers, prove that there exists a finite group G such that G has not a Hall $\pi$-subgroup.
Given a set of prime numbers, $\pi$, I want to prove that if for every finite group G there exists a $\pi$-subgroup of Hall, then
$\pi$ must be empty, contain all prime numbers, or be a single prime number. I then try to formulate a proof by contradiction, attempting to find a group or constructing one, leading to a contradiction. I thought about using induction on the index of the subgroup in the group, but I believe it's incorrect to do so. Therefore, I tried to somehow combine alternating groups and semidirect products to reach some contradiction with the simplicity of $A_n$, but I haven't succeeded. I'm not looking for a proof based on very deep results, but rather a simple one that can be done with the basics of Hall subgroups defined in general, not just in solvable groups.
Another idea was to consider a group of order pm such that m
is a $\pi$-number and p is a prime that is large enough (it would suffice for $p>m-1$) so that its Sylow p-subgroup is normal, but I didn't know what to do with that assumption, I don’t even know if I can assume it.

What if $G$ is a $\pi’$-group, or am I missing something?

What I want to prove is that  I want to prove that if for every finite group G there exists a π-subgroup of Hall, then π must be empty, contain all prime numbers, or be a single prime number; so there is no assumptions about the cardinality of G.

@NickyHekster It may also be that I have not understood what you want to suggest with your question.

I think Lemma 6 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.03184 gives you the groups you need. They are $PSL_2(p)$ for various primes $p$.

@DavidA.Craven Thanks, it is true that it solves my problem but I would like a proof that does not require such a deep theory.

The subgroups of $PSL_2(p)$ and a bit of easy number theory is not deep. If you mean first-course level group theory, I think you will not be getting that.
